# How to programmatically "tap" a UITableView cell?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4, ipad

I was wondering is there a way that I could have my code "tap" a cell in my UITableView in order to reproduce the behaviour specified in the `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` delegate method.

I guess in other words, is is possible to invoke the `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` delegate method programatically?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Can't you put any logic in didSelectRowAtIndexPath into a separate method and just call that method from both didSelectRowAtIndexPath and wherever else you want to call the same code?

Comment: Yes but the cell doesn't get highlighted like it does when you tap. Any ideas there?

Comment: @BeemerFan: Just call from the method that calls the new, common method: [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:myIndexPath animated:false scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];

Answer (score 39):

if you want to have the cell selected, i.e highlight a specific cell:

```
//select first row of first section
NSIndexPath* selectedCellIndexPath= [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
[self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:selectedCellIndexPath animated:false scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];
```

if you want to additionally trigger actions in your didSelectRowAtIndexPath method, you need to manually call the delegate method, it won't happen automatically:

```
[self tableView:self.tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:selectedCellIndexPath];
```

Comment: Calling didSelectRowAtIndexPath does not trigger segues though.

Comment: Yes it does. Works for me.

Answer (score 7):

Swift 3.2 Solution

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 2, section: 0)  // change row and section according to you
tblView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
tblView.delegate?.tableView!(tblView, didSelectRowAt: indexPath)
```

Comment: Seems like it was taken here https://stackoverflow.com/a/40590050/5790492 !

Answer (score 2):

It's just a method. Go ahead and invoke it like you'd invoke any other method.

Comment: That actually is an instance method, not a class method - but hey, that might be nitpicking :D.

Answer (score 1):

This is a 6.1 update. When you are using segues- all the advice is good, but you also have to invoke the segue. So - to add to the advice and summarize it

```
// ... assuming we just added a new row - which is one use of what this thread is trying to do

/* get new count - this is the row we are going to highlight - 0 based */
 int newIndex = [dataArrayUnderlyingTable count]-1; 

/* make it look pretty by highlighting it */
    NSIndexPath *nip = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:newIndex inSection:0];
    [[self tableView] selectRowAtIndexPath:nip animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom];

/* run the code in the following method so it is not missed */
    [self tableView:[self tableView] didSelectRowAtIndexPath:nip];

/* now 'tap' on it ... or simulate it */
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"viewChildDetails" sender: self];
```