# Manually call didSelectRowatIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to call didSelectRowAtIndexPath programmatically but am having trouble.

```
[self tableView:playListTbl didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Gives me the following error:

> Use of undeclared identifier 'indexPath'; did you mean 'NSIndexPath'?

Can anybody help me out?  Thanks!

EDIT:  From the responses below it sounds like im going about this the wrong way.  How can I get the text of the selected items when a button is pressed (can be multiple selections)?  I need to do this in a function dedicated to the button press.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You need to pass a valid argument, if you haven't declared `indexPath` in the calling scope then you'll get that error. Try:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:ROW_YOU_WANT_TO_SELECT inSection:SECTION_YOU_WANT_TO_SELECT]
[self tableView:playListTbl didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Where `ROW_YOU_WANT...` are to be replaced with the row and section you wish to select.

However, you really shouldn't ever call this directly. Extract the work being done inside `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` into separate methods and call those directly.

To address the updated question, you need to use the `indexPathsForSelectedRows` method on `UITableView`. Imagine you were populating the table cell text from an array of arrays of strings, something like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tv dequeue...];
        NSArray *rowsForSection = self.sectionsArray[indexPath.section];
        NSString *textForRow = rowsForSection[indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = textForRow;
        return cell;
    }
```

Then, to get all the selected text, you'd want to do something like:

```
NSArray *selectedIndexPaths = [self.tableView indexPathsForSelectedRows];
NSMutableArray *selectedTexts = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSIndexPath *indexPath in selectedIndexPaths) {
    NSArray *section = self.sectionsArray[indexPath.section];
    NSString *text = section[indexPath.row];
    [selectedTexts addObject:text];
}
```

`selectedTexts` would at that point contain all selected information. Hopefully that example makes sense.

Comment: It looks like im definitely not going about my approach the right way, basically I would like to get all of the text of the selected items in a UITableView when a button is clicked.  I will revise my original post.  Might be a question for another topic but i will check this as the answer to this one.

Comment: @johnhannigan OK, that's a completely different question.

Comment: Yup your right but thank you  i will check this as the answer to this one

Answer (score 39):

**Swift Solution**

***Manually call didSelectRowAtIndexPath***

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 7, section: 0)
tblView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .top)
tblView.delegate?.tableView!(tblView, didSelectRowAt: indexPath)
```

Comment: @Strange welcome, Please could you tell me about scroll position middle changes? why it is required

let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 7, section: 0)
tblView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .middle)
tblView.delegate?.tableView!(tblView, didSelectRowAt: indexPath)

Comment: @SourabhSharma see new function asks for UITableViewScrollPosition so you need to give either of the available options, I gave middle so that the selected row can scroll to the middle of UITableView.

Answer (score 9):

Just to update [*@Sourabh's answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40590050/4927984), note that you can also provide a `scrollPosition` when calling `selectRow`:

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 7, section: 0)
tblView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
tblView.delegate?.tableView!(tblView, didSelectRowAt: indexPath)
```

Becomes:

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 7, section: 0)
tblView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .top) // <--
tblView.delegate?.tableView!(tblView, didSelectRowAt: indexPath)
```

The [possible constants](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewscrollposition) are:

> #### `.none`
>
> The table view scrolls the row of interest to be fully visible with a
>   minimum of movement. If the row is already fully visible, no scrolling
>   occurs. For example, if the row is above the visible area, the
>   behavior is identical to that specified by top. This is the default.
>
> #### `.top`
>
> The table view scrolls the row of interest to the top of the visible
>   table view.
>
> #### `.middle`
>
> The table view scrolls the row of interest to the middle of the
>   visible table view.
>
> #### `.bottom`
>
> The table view scrolls the row of interest to the bottom of the
>   visible table view.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define an indexPath variable if you don't already have one to stick in there.

Something like:

```
    NSIndexPath * indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting from [Mistalis answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44041342/1121497), I made this little `ExtendedCell` class because I use it in several table views.

Usage in table view:

```
// Here MyTableView is UITableView and UITableViewDelegate
// but you can separate them.

class MyTableView: UITableView, UITableViewDelegate {

    override func dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier identifier: String) -> UITableViewCell? {
        return MyCell(identifier: identifier, table: self)
    }

    // ...
}
```

Implementation of your cell:

```
class MyCell : ExtendedCell {

    convenience init(identifier: String?, table: MyTableView)
    {
        // in this example, MyTableView is both table and delegate
        self.init(identifier: identifier, table: table, delegate: table)

        // ...
    }

    // At any moment you may call selectTableRow() to select
    // the row associated to this cell.
    func viewItemDetail() {
      selectTableRow()
    }
}
```

`ExtendedCell` class:

```
import UIKit

/**
 * UITableViewCell with extended functionality like
 * the ability to trigger a selected row on the table
 */
class ExtendedCell : UITableViewCell {

    // We store the table and delegate to trigger the selected cell
    // See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18245441/manually-call-did-select-row-at-index-path

    weak var table : UITableView!
    weak var delegate : UITableViewDelegate!

    convenience init(identifier: String?, table: UITableView, delegate: UITableViewDelegate)
    {
        self.init(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: identifier)

        self.table = table
        self.delegate = delegate
    }

    func selectTableRow()
    {
        if let indexPath = table.indexPath(for: self) {
            table.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .none)
            delegate.tableView!(table, didSelectRowAt: indexPath)
        }
    }
}
```