# Capture cell being pressed without didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have the following `UITableViewCell` (well, subclassed).

[image]

With `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` it is possible to capture that a cell has been selected in `UITableViewController`. My problem occurs due to the fact that directly pressing `Choose User` bypasses the selection of the cell.

How could I allow my `UITableViewController` to be aware that `UITableViewCell` foo has been pressed even if the user immediately hits `Choose User`?

N.B. I don't *need* the Selection capability per se, this was just by method of knowing that a user had tapped within a cell area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just call the method directly. If we say that for each `Choose User` button we are setting the row number as the `tag` and assuming that you don't have sections so everything will happen in section `0` we could do.

```
- (void)hitChooseUser:(id)sender
{
    // Do whatever you want for when a user hits the `Choose User` button
    // Code......

    // Then do this at the end or whenever you want to do it.
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[sender tag] inSection:0];
    // Also assuming you have created you have created you UITableView correctly.
    [self tableView:myTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Do whatever it is you want.
}
```

I also found this link that may help you [Manually call didSelectRowatIndexPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18245441/manually-call-didselectrowatindexpath)

You could also disable the user interaction with the cell itself by setting `userInteractionEnabled:` to `NO` for each cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` so `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` will only get called when you want to call it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Do not call `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`  It is a `UITableViewDelegate` method and, where possible, should be used as such (meaning let the `UITableView` send messages to it).  In addition, it creates an unnecessary dependency on `UITableView` implementation.

That being said, in order to achieve shared behavior that is performed either on button click, or on row selection, refactor it out into a common method that is not coupled with `UITableViewDelegate`

For example:

```
-(void)doSomethingCommon {
    //do shared code here
}

-(void)chooseUserButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    [self doSomethingCommon];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [self doSomethingCommon];
}
```

And if your `UITableView` shows more than one of these rows, for which you depend on knowing which corresponding model object is related to the cell, than you can use the `tag` property on `UIView` subclasses (usually something in your cell) to mark the row that the object is shown in.