# Animating the TableView cell using CGAffineTransformScale upon tap and remove the animation upon tableView scroll

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

How to animating the tapped tableView cell and animate it like using CGAffineTransformScale and remove the animation when the tableView is scrolled. If the cell tap get tapped-out event I need to call didSelect tableView cell method.

## CustomTableViewCell Class

```
import UIKit

class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var cellDataView: UIView!

    var longTapCallback: ((_ success: Bool) -> Void)?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.setLongTapGuesture()
    }

    func setLongTapGuesture() {
        let guesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(CustomTableViewCell.lognTaponCell))
        self.contentView.addGestureRecognizer(guesture)
    }

    @objc func lognTaponCell(guesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
        if guesture.state != .ended {
            self.longTapCallback?(true)
        } else {
            self.longTapCallback?(false)
        }
    }
}
```

## ViewController class

```
import UIKit

class AnimationTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 15
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier", for: indexPath) as? CustomTableViewCell

        cell?.longTapCallback = { (success) in
            if success {
                self.selectedIndexPath = indexPath
                self.startLongTapGuesture(atCell: cell!)

            } else {
                self.stopLongTapGuesture(atCell: cell!)
            }
        }
        return cell!
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("Did Select Called")
    }
}

extension AnimationTableViewController {

    func startLongTapGuesture(atCell cell: CustomTableViewCell) {

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.0, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.6, initialSpringVelocity: 6, options: .beginFromCurrentState, animations: {

        }, completion: { (finished) in
            cell.contentView.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(scaleX: 1.6, y: 1.6)
    })
}

func stopLongTapGuesture(atCell cell: CustomTableViewCell) {

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.0, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.6, initialSpringVelocity: 6, options: [], animations: {

    }, completion: { (finished) in
        cell.contentView.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(scaleX: 1, y: 1)
    })
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 120.0
}}
```

**Screenshot from simulator:**

[image]

Comment: What exactly is your issue ? You need to figure out how to trigger didSelectRowAt when long tapped ?? Is that all ??

Comment: I need to animate the tapped cell same as in AppStore application, when the cell is long tapped it will show Tapped-In animation until we scroll or if we don't scroll it will be redirected to the respective page, this is what i want to achieve.

Comment: Though am not entirely sure of which animation you are talking about you can stop the animation added by calling `self.longTapCallback?(false) ` in `prepareForReuse` method of your cell so that animation stops before cell gets reused. Finally if you want to trigger didSelectRowAt programmatically you can always trigger at as shown here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18245441/manually-call-didselectrowatindexpath and if your intention is to stop animation as soon as tableView scrolls you can use scrollViewDidScroll delegate of UIScrollView and call stopLongTapGuesture on all visible cells

Comment: I tried using scrollViewDidScroll method to stop the animation, but in this method i will not get access to the cell (indexPath) to stop animation which is been applied currently, I tried storing the selected cell indexpath but it wont work.

Comment: You need not :) when scrollViewDidScroll gets called get the indexPath in visible range that will give you a array of indexPath which are currently visible iterate over it (it will be limited so dont worry :)) get the cell using indexPath and then call stopLongTapGuesture on the cell :) Simple not very efficient way though I must add but will do your job for sure :)

Comment: I did this using using scrollViewDidScroll method, i wont get my actual requirement form this. I am expecting to get the functionality like AppStore application (Today tab) in iPhone. I request you to please have a look at AppStore Application and help me to achieve this.

Comment: When you say 'animate' do you in fact mean you want the selected cell to be larger and then to shrink back when another cell is selected (with the new cell becoming larger).  Now it may animate the growing and shrinking but it should stay larger while selected.

Comment: Yes this is my exact requirement.

Comment: Do you also want the selected cell to go over the top of the cells around it?

Comment: I just checked out the AppStore and see what you are trying to achieve.  While the finger is on the cell it shrinks down slightly and then when you release it fills the screen.  Is that the kind of thing?  (What version of iOS and device are you targeting)

Comment: Ye the selected cell needs to shrink to certain extent until the user removes long tap on cell, Once the user stop long tap on cell, i am calling the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method as given in my answer below.

I am removing this animation when the user scrolls the TableView, by detecting the scroll event form scrollViewDidScroll method.

I am targeting iOS 11 as it is a practice scenario for me.

Comment: While you may all didSelectRowAtIndexPath the system will also call that automatically and I don't think you have much control over this.  Are you trying to replicate what the App Store Today tab does?

Comment: Yes i am trying to create the Same UI as AppStore app today tab. I have got that working with the below mentioned answer. Please let me know is that the correct way of getting thing done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i have mentioned above, i have used a closure call back for getting the long tap gesture on TableViewCell.

My scenario :

1. I need to animate the cell until the user taps on cell
2. Once the user stops holding the cell, i need to call **didSelectRowAtIndexPath** Method.
3. If TableView scroll is detected, I will remove the animation applied to the cell Object by iterating the visible cells in the **scrollViewDidScroll** method as given below.

   ```
   override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
      let cellsArray = self.tableView.visibleCells
          for cell in cellsArray {
             UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.0, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.6, initialSpringVelocity: 6, options: [], animations: {

       }, completion: { (finished) in
           cell.contentView.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(scaleX: 1, y: 1)
       })
   }}
   ```

I have modified the **cellForRowAtIndexPath** method as given below:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier", for: indexPath) as? CustomTableViewCell

    cell?.longTapCallback = { (success) in
        if success {

            //Identifies the Long Tap on the Cell.
            self.startLongTapGuesture(atCell: cell!)

        } else {
            //Identifies the Release of Long tap on Cell.
            self.tableView(self.tableView, didSelectRowAt: indexPath)
        }
    }
    return cell!
}
```

This works Similer to AppStore application. Thanks for the giving useful idea form you comments **Mr.Sandeep Bhandari's.**