# How to turn [didSelectRowAtIndexPath] selected cell into a string for later use

Tags: ios, iphone, nsstring, didselectrowatindexpath, nsindexpath

I'm looking to find a way to add the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` 'cell name' that is selected in the table through the `didDismissWithButtonIndex:` method:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
if (buttonIndex == 1) {


Database *currentStore = [DBList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

NSString *requestStr = @"http://";
requestStr = [requestStr stringByAppendingString:hostTextField.text];
requestStr = [requestStr stringByAppendingString:@":8080/compfile2.php?password="];
requestStr = [requestStr stringByAppendingString:passwordTextField.text];
requestStr = [requestStr stringByAppendingString:@"&db=latinbites"];
requestStr = [requestStr stringByAppendingString:currentStore];


}
```

Obviously, the

```
Database *currentStore = [DBList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

isn't correct. Is there a way I can put a string on the selected cell row?

Comment: I'm not sure how you are relating the UIAlertViewDelegate didDismissWithButtonIndex to the a table view's didSelectRowAtIndexPath. Do you want to simulate a user touch on the table view to select the cell corresponding to the button index? Where is indexPath.row coming from?

Comment: Yes, what you said last.

Comment: The cells in my table are individual objects (databases) from the query: [SHOW DATABASES]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I understand what you want to achieve. Try to following code:-

**No. 1** - Declare a property with NSString

```
@interface TableViewController ()<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString * selectedCellName;
@end
```

**No. 2** - In **didSelectRowAtIndexPath**

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
self.selectedCellName = cell.textLabel.text;
}
```

**No. 3** - In **didDismissWithButtonIndex**, append the cell name.

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
if (buttonIndex == 1) {

NSString *requestStr = @"http://";
requestStr = [requestStr stringByAppendingString:hostTextField.text];
requestStr = [requestStr stringByAppendingString:@":8080/compfile2.php?password="];
requestStr = [requestStr stringByAppendingString:passwordTextField.text];
requestStr = [requestStr stringByAppendingString:@"&db=latinbites"];
requestStr = [requestStr stringByAppendingString:self.selectedCellName];
}
}
```

Comment: No problem. Thanks for accepting as answer too. I am glad that I am able to help you. ;)

Answer (score 0):

As confusing as what you want to do is (why not just have them tap on the table, not the alert view?), it can be done.

First, see [How to programmatically “tap” a UITableView cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5918309/189804) - all you need after that is to make a `NSIndexPath` object to send to that method.

```
NSIndexPath *cellToTap = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:buttonIndex inSection:theSection];
```

What theSection should be is up to you. If you have just one section in your table view it is 0.

Comment: in my app, tapping the cell brings up the alert view and two options. (cancel, add).  the add button adds a bunch of information to SQLite database.

Comment: Fair enough. Well, just calling didSelectRowAtIndexPath should work. The things the tableView does before calling this method are cosmetic, any model change is left up to you - so you get exactly the same effect as if you actually had a finger tapping that cell.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the UITableView method called `indexPathForSelectedRow`.  So long as there is still a selection, this will answer the index path you need.

If there's a chance that the selection can be lost (after the user selects and before the alert is dismissed) then the safer bet is to record the selection in a property when the didSelect method fires.

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (buttonIndex == 1) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        Database *currentStore = DBList[indexPath.row];
        // ...
```