# UITableView row selection and tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)

Tags: swift, uitableview, uitableviewrowaction

I do row selection in my code

```
tbvCounters.selectRow(at: counterIndexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .middle)
```

and I assume that protocol method

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```

should be triggered but it`s not. It works fine when I tap the row of UITableView as user action.
How I could simulate user tapping ti trigger "didSelectRowAt" method?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to programmatically "tap" a UITableView cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5918309/how-to-programmatically-tap-a-uitableview-cell)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

`selectRow` doesn't trigger `didSelectRowAt` , but you can trigger with

```
tbvCounters.selectRow(at: counterIndexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .middle)
self.tableView(self.tbvCounters, didSelectRowAt: counterIndexPath)
```

Comment: This is a bad idea. Never directly call delegate and data source methods. Put common in a function and call it as needed.

Comment: your suggestion is off-topic , here discussion about whether it's called or not and How To